# ID a book about a mirror world and 4th dimension

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a book about 10-15 years ago about a boy and a girl who find a mirror. What made the mirror special was, they were able to enter the reflection and be a part of the reverse image world. They end up going to school and when asked to write something on the board, it ends up being backwards, but to them looks normal.

Later, the two end up in a world with 4 dimensions. With the added dimension they can't see as they normally could. If one moved a certain way the other would see their insides. Eventually a native of that dimension made some type of device that lets them see regularly.

Other than that my memory is blank. If I remember anything else I will be sure to edit it in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help Identify Youth novel about higher dimensions](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/75860/help-identify-youth-novel-about-higher-dimensions)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is *probably* [The Boy Who Reversed Himself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Boy_Who_Reversed_Himself). There's no actual mirror involved, but there is a bit of mirror/backwards writing, and the boy and girl end up in the 4th dimension, where one of them is given a device that lets them see "correctly".

Comment: thank you. i've been trying to find this one for quite some time. it's a shame i can only up vote once for the answer. thanks again.